# What's up in this SPAWAR video?

Tags: physical-chemistry, electrochemistry, cold-fusion

Here is a video presentation of infrared recordings of anomalous heating in a deuterium palladium cell: ( [youtube video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Pb9V_qFKf2M&feature=relmfu)) (see also [this presentation](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=N2LV8rM7vn0) if you want more detail, and have time). There are two papers referenced in the link, which give more detail. You can see with your own eyes sporadic localized bursts of energy, which show up as white flashes in the camera (I would like to encourage people to read the linked papers, which include thermal photos with a different color map, and also include piezoelectric detection of bursts)

Excluding cold fusion, what could possibly be causing this? Please try to account for the nature of the bursts--- the small radius, the qualitative amount of energy released, etc.

Just to be clear, I think the answer is *nothing*, that it is cold fusion, but I would like to see what explanations people come up with. I will also point out that this research group has been [politically shut down recently](http://blog.newenergytimes.com/2012/03/01/navy-commander-halts-spawar-lenr-research/).

Answer (score 3):

Without knowing anything about the experiment nor the camera, I would suggest that what is shown in the video is a combination of [shot noise](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shot_noise) and aliasing due to a poor choice of gradient mapping. Note that the gradient bar at the bottom of the frame jumps from a fairly deep red (actually darker than precedent tones) to pure white in one increment - this may result in small fluctuations in temperature appearing much more visually significant than they are.

I had a go at my own gradient maps (in Photoshop) to show off this effect - I tried to go for something similar to their gradient mapping, which for all I know is hardwired into the camera:

[image]

Something to consider. I read an article recently about injudicious gradient mapping overemphasising tiny differences in geospatial and medical datasets (and also obscuring important distinctions in other scenarios). It's a good read and I'll link it when I find it again.

Comment: This is nonsense, but at least it is a decent attempt. The presentation linked through the video gives a nondistorted all blue map, which shows localized heat. The blue spots are acoompanied by a temperature increase in the whole electrode, and this is not an artifact--- the $\Delta T$ on electrode is 17 degs. In their blue map, there is a central region which is hotter, with hotter spots still. Where is this heat coming from? The curve you see every once in a while in the video is the temperature gradient in profile away from the electrode.

Comment: Shot noise seems like a reasonable explanation to me. All I see there is a grainy image. Also, I must say that the quality of the entire presentation seems quite low. No mention of any control experiments or characterization of their detectors, no quantitative analysis of these "hot spots", no correlative measurements between their camera/piezo detector. It is very unconvincing to me.

Comment: Shot noise is not a reasonable explanation--- you should see a white region with shot noise at the boundary if this is what is going on. You can see the shot noise in the boundary of the other temperature regions--- where there is a smooth transition, with a little bit of oscillating color. The inner white spots are everywhere interspersed with red, which requires that the whole white-red region is always _exactly_ tuned to be at the red/white boundary. This is just impossible--- note that the number of white spots increases without a solid white region emerging. I am dismayed at the upvotes.

Comment: @RonMaimon I have a ton of respect for your physics knowledge and intelligence, but do you mind if I ask what experience you have with experimental science? This seems easily explainable as measurement noise to me. Their imaging system is low resolution and has a lot of variance, which is visible in the sections of the line profile which lie outside the electrode - the level of variance does not look substantially smaller than the center.

Comment: Also, take a look at this screenshot of the video, which I believe show the limitations of their imaging detector: http://imgur.com/FuTkX

Comment: Can you give a physical explanation for the anisotropy of the white segments?

Comment: Finally, I'd like to reiterate that I think this is very poor science, even if the effect is real: these kinds of doubts could easily by reduced by showing some basic control experiments, such as imaging with the current off, or using a resistive heater to warm the electrode without the reaction and comparing.

Comment: @zephyr: I have no experience in anything, no credentials here. Your explanation is superficially plausible, and a good attempt to explain the thing, so I took away the downvote. But it just cannot be right. If you look at any frame of the video, the white and red pixels are intermingled all the time, which means that the whole speckled region has to be tuned just right, to be at the boundary temperature. This defies the imagination, why would the electrode plateau at the exact boundary temperature of the camera?

Comment: The video is not trying to establish that there are hot-spots, rather it is trying to establish only that the electrode is hotter than the solution, and for this purpose, it is sufficient. This behavior is opposite of normal electrochemistry. The linked papers _do_ talk about the hot-spots and use a different color map, plus a piezoelectric detector, so I don't think your criticism is apropos. I only linked to the video, because you can see funny stuff going on with your own eyes--- hot electrode and weird "shot noise" as you put it that looks much more plausibly like random localized heating.

Answer (score 3):

I'm an experimental electrochemist. The problem with experiments such as those mentioned above is that they lack the necessary details to reproduce it, so that we can verify it or improve upon it.

In the first video, a paper linked is here: http://www.lenr-canr.org/acrobat/SzpakSpolarizedd.pdf

They vaguely mention a "negatively polarized Pd/D$_2$O system". Then they refer us to Figure 6 for more "complete" experimental details. Let's ignore all the piezo stuff. We have a potentiostat (what kind), with electrodes (unspecified counterelectrode and a vague Pd/D film working electrode without mention of preparative conditions), in an undefined electrodeposition solution with unknown concentrations or purities of reagents, and without any mention of the voltage/settings applied on the potentiostat during the course of the experiment. Moreover, they do not tell us about the thermal scanner, even the make or model. There is a mention to other journals but a quick glance at the few I could easily access online did not illuminate any of these details better. Was the container even cleaned for trace impurities?

In an excellent paper you will find all these experimental details and more. In a field which is highly contested among leaders in electrochemistry you are already held to a higher bar of scrutiny and as such greater care must be taken in reporting your results for any serious scholarly interest. Lacking these important details makes the entire paper worthless. If this were an undergrad's first lab report given me to then I wouldn't even award a D-. This is especially true when people in cold fusion report that it is very sensitive to experimental details/preparation.

This "paper" also suffers because it does not address why this could not be due to joule heating, a more likely scenario but cannot be judged without knowing the voltages or currents involved.

If you can find a paper (with the PDF) that has a complete experimental then e-mail it to me and I'll take a closer look. I would honestly really love for cold fusion to be true and to see if it could work, but the work I've seen doesn't even hold a candle to the care you'll find in a Letter published in the Journal of the American Chemical Society and therefore I cannot spend my time trying to reproduce these results.

Comment: This is a nice honest answer. I'll try to dig up the review and link it here. I think you are not fair to these folks, they have published many of their results in journals, and the reagents and concentrations for the experiment are widely available in the CF field, in the SPAWAR published papers. The field is neglected, and the papers tend to look bad, but that's not a way to evaluate experimental results--- you need to look at the data, even if it looks crappy, and see if there is an anomalous effect.